# In UWP/XAML How do I make the SplitView.Content fill the remaining space in a window?

Tags: c#, xaml, layout, uwp

I'm trying to control the layout of a Universal Windows Platform app without much success.

Here is a screenshot of the layout: 
[Application Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZyrW.jpg)

How do I make the "Search" area on the right (outlined in a black border) fill the remaining space to the right?

The main area of the application is a SplitView container. To the left is a ListBox with the navigation menu items which is contained in the SplitView.Pane. To the right is the SplitView.Content containing a Frame where the SearchPage will be displayed . When the "Search" menu item is clicked I navigate to the SearchPage using:

```
private void NavigationList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (createNavigationItem.IsSelected)
    {
        mainFrame.Navigate(typeof(CreatePage));
    }
    else if (searchNavigationItem.IsSelected)
    {
        mainFrame.Navigate(typeof(SearchPage));
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell the problem is not with the SearchPage. I would like to force the SplitView.Content to simply fill the remaining available space in the window. Similar to setting `<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />` in a grid.

The only way I have been able to get any success is to explicitly set the width of the content on the SearchPage. Then the Frame grows to accommodate the content and subsequently so does the SplitView.Content. I want my app to be responsive and not rely on explicit sizes though.

Here is the XAML of the main window that contains the SplitView:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/> 
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <RelativePanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Button Name="hamburgerButton" 
                    RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                    FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" 
                    FontSize="20" 
                    FontWeight="ExtraBold"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    Content="&#xE700;" 
                    Click="HamburgerButton_Click"/>
        </RelativePanel>

        <SplitView Name="navigationSplitView" 
                   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                   DisplayMode="Inline" 
                   OpenPaneLength="180"
                   CompactPaneLength="41"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <ListBox Name="navigationList" 
                         SelectionMode="Single" 
                         SelectionChanged="NavigationList_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBoxItem Name="createNavigationItem">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="20" Text="&#xE10F;"/>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="Create" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="searchNavigationItem">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Text="&#xE1A3;"/>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="Search" Margin="12,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox>
            </SplitView.Pane>
            <SplitView.Content>
                <Frame Name="mainFrame"
                       BorderBrush="Black"
                       BorderThickness="10"/>
            </SplitView.Content>
        </SplitView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And here is the XAML of the SearchPage

```
<Page
    x:Class="RecipeMaker.SearchPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:RecipeMaker"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock FontSize="36" Text="Search"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: You may use [NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) directly other than define your own nav left pane

Comment: The NuGet package it is contained in requires the most recent version of Windows 10 version 1809 (even though their documentation pointing to the package indicates otherwise). I need to support earlier versions of Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Stretch

```
    <SplitView Name="navigationSplitView" 
           Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
           DisplayMode="Inline" 
           CompactPaneLength="41"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
```

Comment: That was it. I had tried setting Stretch on everything except (apparently) the SplitView itself. I knew it would be something simple like that. Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes.